# How can we determine the point at which the distance between vectors is equal to a certain constant?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, angle

Consider the following points:

$$A(-3,0)\hspace{1cm}
B(3,0)\hspace{1cm}
C(x,y)$$

Now consider the following vectors:

$$CA\hspace{1cm}
CB\hspace{1cm}
CO$$

where $O$ is the origin $O(0,0)$.
Consider the vector $HF$, of magnitude $4$. It is perpendicular to the position vector $OC$ of $C$. All this is depicted in the diagram below. How can the position of $E$ or of $H$ and $F$ be determined with respect to $C(x,y)$ while maintaining a magnitude of $4$?

TL;DR? Essentially, considering the diagram below and that $C$ is an arbitrary point, where must $E$ be in order to achieve a length of $4$ for $FH$.

[image: Diagram]

Badly worded question, I know, but I can't seem to simplify it nor answer it.

Thanks,

Yazan

Comment: Do you know the different ways to express the equation of a line, such as parametric equations, cartesian equations,...? For example, for a line in $\Bbb R^{2}$ with $(v_{x},v_{y})$ as direction vector and passing throug $(x_{0},y_{0})$: $$\begin{cases}x&=x_{0}+\lambda v_{x}\\y&=y_{0}+\lambda v_{y}\end{cases}$$ where $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not colinear and that neither of the lines $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ is perpendicular to the line $\overline{OC}$. Observe that $|EF|=|CE|\tan{\angle{FCE}}$ and $|EH|=|CE|\tan{\angle{ECH}}$, so $$|CE|={|FH|\over\tan{\angle{FCE}}+\tan{\angle{ECH}}}.$$ The denominator can be computed using dot products and cross products: $$\tan{\angle{FCE}}={\sin{\angle{FCE}}\over\cos{\angle{FCE}}}={\|A-C\|\|C\|\sin{\angle{FCE}}\over\|A-C\|\|C\|\cos{\angle{FCE}}}={(A-C)\times C\over(A-C)\cdot C}\tag{*}$$ and similarly for $\tan{\angle{ECH}}$. Note that there will be two such points, one to either side of $C$ along the line $\overline{OC}$. By cross-product here I mean the “two-dimensional cross product” $$\mathbf u\times\mathbf v=\det\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u&\mathbf v\end{bmatrix}=x_uy_v-y_vx_u,$$ which is the value of the $z$-coordinate of the three-dimensional cross product of these vectors. Take care to maintain the proper order of the vectors when computing $\tan{\angle{ECH}}$. The numerator of (*) can of course be simplified to $A\times C$, but it’s not really any more computationally efficient to do so.

Comment: This simply provides the answer. Thank you. However, I believe (A−C)⋅C should be |(A−C)⋅C|.

Comment: @Yazan The absolute value was an abuse of notation on my part. I meant the “2-D cross product,” i.e., the $z$-coordinate of the cross product. The signs of both numerator and denominator must be maintained, otherwise the formula fails for $C$ near the $x$-axis with $x$-coordinate between that of $A$ and $B$. I’ve updated my answer to clarify. Please accept it if it has answered the question to your satisfaction.

Comment: One last, quick question that is likely answered by the obvious: How did you come to combine the two equations at the beginning into that definition for |CE|? Also, how did you manage to substitute the sin and cos angles to dot and cross products? Could you please expand a little on how these operations were done? Thanks.

Comment: @Yazan $|FH|=|FE|+|EH|$, then solve for $|CE|$. The last expression in (*) follows directly from the definitions of the cross and dot products.

Answer (score 2):

I won't do all the calculations since I didn't find a *nice* method. However, the reasoning I follow is simple to understand, despite involving horrible expressions.

In the sequel, I denote by $d_{XY}$ a line passing thgrouh distincts points $X$ and $Y$. I also take $C(\alpha,\beta)$ to avoid confusion and since we don't look for $C$ but for $E$, so the coordinates of $C$ are parameters.

## First case: $C$ does not lie on an axis

As the title says, we consider that $C$ does not lie on an axis. Thus, $\alpha\neq 0$ and $\beta\neq 0$. We can directly deduce the following equations:

\begin{align*}
d_{CA}\equiv y&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha+3}(x+3)\\
d_{CB}\equiv y&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-3}(x-3)\\
d_{CO}\equiv y&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}x
\end{align*}

**Note**: you have to discuss $\alpha=\pm 3$.

Let $\{d_{p}\vert p\in\Bbb R\}$ be the family of lines that are perpendicular to $d_{CO}$. We have (for any $p\in\Bbb R$):

$$d_{p}\equiv y=\frac{-\alpha}{\beta}x+p$$

since two lines are perpendicular iff the product of their respective slopes is equal to $-1$. Note that there is only one $p$ that will give the "correct" line. We shall be able to express the coordinates of $F$ and $H$ in terms of $p$ and determine $p$ via the condition $\vert HF\vert=4$.

You can now see that $F=d_{CA}\cap d_{p}$ and $H=d_{CB}\cap d_{p}$ for a particular $p$. We have for $d_{CA}\cap d_{p}$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{-\alpha}{\beta}x_{F} +p&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha+3}(x+3)\\
\iff x_{F} &= \frac{p-\frac{3\beta}{\alpha+3}}{\frac{\beta}{\alpha+3}+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\\
&=\left(p-\frac{3\beta}{\alpha+3}\right)\frac{\beta(\alpha+3)}{\beta^{2}+\alpha(\alpha+3)}
\end{align*}

**Note**: you have to discuss the case where the denominators are $0$ separately. This can be partially overcome using parametric equations instead of cartesian ones but I don't know if you know these concepts.

Similarly, for $x_{H}$, we obtain:

$$x_{H}=\left(p+\frac{3\beta}{\alpha-3}\right)\frac{\beta(\alpha-3)}{\beta^{2}+\alpha(\alpha-3)}$$

You then deduce $y_{F}$ and $y_{H}$ using the fact that $F\in d_{CA}$ and $H\in d_{CB}$:

\begin{align*}
y_{F} &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha+3}\left(x_{F}+3\right)\\
y_{H} &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-3}\left(x_{H}-3\right)
\end{align*}

Now, use the fact that $\vert HF\vert = 4$, that is:

$$(x_{F}-x_{H})^{2}+(y_{F}-y_{H})^{2}=16$$

This equation only depends on $p$ and you can thus determine the latter. I didn't do the calculations but you shall probably have two values for $p$. One of these two values correspond to the central symmetry around $C$. As $E$ will always be closer to the origin than $C$, you can rule one of these two values according to that criterion.

Now that you have determined $p$, you have determined the coordinates of $F$ and $H$ (of course, they depend on $\alpha,\beta$). But you can also directly get $E$ by calculating $d_{p}\cap d_{CO}$. We obtain:

$$E=\left(p\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\,,\,p\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)$$

## Second case: $C$ lies on an axis

We suppose $C\neq O$ (if it is the case, $E=O$). If $C$ lies on the $x$ axis, there is obviously an infinity of solutions that you can easily write down (but $E$ will be on the $x$ axis as well). If $C$ lies on the $y$ axis, that is $C=(0,\beta)$ with $\beta\neq 0$, then $E$ as well. In that case, by the Thales theorem, we know that

$$\frac{\vert FH\vert}{\vert AB\vert}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{\vert CE\vert}{\vert CO\vert}\iff \vert CE\vert=\frac{2}{3}\vert\beta\vert$$

Now, this yields:

$$y_{E}=\beta\mp\frac{2}{3}\beta$$

We can rule out one of these two values with the fact that $E$ must be closer to the origin than $C$. Thus,

$$y_{E}=\frac{1}{3}\beta$$

Comment: Hello. You clearly put in a lot of effort here and I greatly appreciate it. I've tried following through the steps you did but can't comprehend the first case. The second case is simple enough. Could you please elaborate a little on why you've done what you have with a few annotations? I tend to get lost in the notations. Also, feel free to use parametric form if you feel it'll get the point across.

Comment: @Yazan I get that it is difficult to grasp such an explanation when there are so many notations. I shall try to clarify that. I should also say that the answer, [given below by amd](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2069974/283812), is way simpler and faster. I didn't think about using trigonometry, which was silly of me.

Comment: Well, I have gone through your answer again thoroughly with a freshened perspective and it has made sense. I tried to apply Case A (doing the painfully long calculations) and used SymboLab to avoid human error in the longer parts. I defined point C to determine p and thus E, however the answer that it yields is far off the actual point E, regardless of which p is used. Has there been some human error along the way or have I misunderstood the answer? As for amd's answer, I cannot see how that can be applied to find E.

Comment: Nevermind, I now get how that answer can be applied. Excuse my momentary stupidity.

Comment: You might be able to avoid some of the case analysis by setting $E=tC$ (equivalent to your parameter $p$) and moving to homogeneous coordinates, i.e., working in $\mathbb P^2$ instead of $\mathbb R^2$. I believe that you’ll end up with a quadratic equation for $t$ that has a factor of $\beta^2$ (more generally, $\det\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C\end{bmatrix}$) in the denominator. If that’s zero, the points are colinear.

Comment: In your first case, the denominators are zero when $OC$ is perpendicular to one of the other lines (it’s the dot product of $C$ and $A-C$ or $B-C$), so the only possible solution is $C=E$, which forces $F$ or $H$ to also equal $C$. For the case in which $C\ne0$ is on the $x$-axis, I’d say there’s *no* solution rather than in infinite number of them: the distance between the lines is measured in a direction orthogonal to $\overline{OC}$, but that’s uniformly zero in this case.